# Values from MLDataType in MLDataTable

Tags: swift, nlp

I am trying to capture the MLDataValues inside MLDataTable used for MLWordTagger.  The following is  JSON file that can be read in in be a MLDataTable.

```
[
{
"tokens": ["My","shoes", "are,", "blue" ],
"labels": ["NONE","CLOTHING","NONE","COLOR"]
},
{
"tokens": ["Her","hat","is","big,","and","red"],
"labels": ["NONE","CLOTHING","NONE","NONE","NONE","COLOR"]
}
]
```

The following code reads the file in from Desktop and creates a MLDataTable

```
import NaturalLanguage
import CreateML
import Foundation

let homeURL = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
let desktopURL = homeURL.appendingPathComponent("Desktop/short.json")

let training = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: desktopURL )
print("\(training.size)")
```

The print confirms the table is created:

```
(rows: 2, columns: 2)
```

So there are two table rows.  Each table row contains a row of labels and a row of tokens.  I attempt to grab the values from one row below:

```
training.rows[0].forEach { (key, value)  in
    print("\(key) *** \(value)")
    let test = value.sequenceValue?.dataValue
    print("test:  \(test)")

    if let new = test {
        print("new:  \(new)")
        //print("\(new.stringValue![1])")
    } else {
        print("failed")
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
labels *** DataValue([DataValue("NONE"), DataValue("CLOTHING"),    DataValue("NONE"), DataValue("COLOR")])
test:  Optional([NONE, CLOTHING, NONE, COLOR])
new:  DataValue([DataValue("NONE"), DataValue("CLOTHING"), DataValue("NONE"), DataValue("COLOR")])
tokens *** DataValue([DataValue("My"), DataValue("shoes"), DataValue("are"), DataValue("blue")])
test:  Optional([My, shoes, are, blue])
new:  DataValue([DataValue("My"), DataValue("shoes"), DataValue("are"), DataValue("blue")])
```

"test" seems to be close to my actual need as it is an optional array.  However, the attempt to unwrap that by defining "new" does not work.  "new" is now DataValues.

Furthermore the following both fail:

if let new = test?.sequenceValue?.dataValue.stringValue {
   if let new = test?.stringValue {

Also, attempting to unwrap "new" with the following gives a nil result:

```
print("new:  \(new.stringValue?.dataValue)")
```

I think test comes closest to what I would like to do.  Say with test[1], but I then get a message it cannot be sub-scripted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the data values are a [Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence). I can solve my problem with the following code:

```
training.rows[0].forEach { (key, value)  in
    print("\(key) *** \(value)")
    for aValue in value.sequenceValue! {
        print("aValue:  \(aValue.stringValue ?? "fail")")
}
```